# RegEx Trimming spaces at end of names (not lines) in string

Tags: regex, text, text-editor

Yes, I've looked at several threads, but none is exactly what I need.
Scenario:
List of folders, with the following format:

```
<sep><full name of person><sep><yyyy-mm><sep><full name of person><sep>
```

<'sep'>

may be any of:    \s ( [ { or simply non-existant (empty)

```
<name of person>
```

> contains spaces between names, which I must preserve *only* between
>   names, not after the last name.

I want to extract and separate the information into different fields. 
[EDIT] The First Name field is *optional*, which means it may be empty (I forgot to say this in the first post). The *month* field is also optional but since it isn't affected by this "trailing spaces problem", it didn't need to be mentioned.[END EDIT]

I'm using a tilde(~) as a separator between fields. My RegEx does everything right except one thing: it doesn't remove the trailing spaces of the names.

This is to be executed in a text editor like EmEditor (preferable) or Notepad++, so I need pure RegEx, which means no plug-ins, no programming functions, etc.

My current RegEx is this:

```
FIND:
([\s\(\[\{]*)
    ([\w\s\;]*)
([\s\(\)\[\]\{\}\-]*)
    (\d{4})
([\s\-]*)
    ([\d]{0,2})
([\s\(\)\[\]\{\}\-]*)
    ([\w\s\;]*)
([\s\)\]\}]*)
REPLACE:
\2~\4~\6~\8
```

The "Find" expression is just one line, but I separated it in groups for readability reasons.

Original samples (the dollar sign [$] marks the end of line):

```
full name with spaces    2012 5 Another name with spaces   $
(This is a name) [2010-5] { Full name again }  $
2014-05 nome de pessoa$
```

Here is what I get currently:

```
full name with spaces    ~2012~5~Another name with spaces   ~$
This is a name~2010~5~Full name again ~$
~2014~05~nome de pessoa~$
```

I need to remove those nasty spaces before the tilde(~) or the dollar($) sign. :)
Any help?

[EDIT: ANSWER]
I solved my problem by replacing the two "match name" expressions, with this one, based on the correct answer below:

```
([\w][\s\w]*[\w])?
```

Comment: Can you give any line example ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For selecting the person, use the regex something like this

> ([\w][\s\w]*[\w])

So, it starts with a letter, has spaces or letters in between, and ends with a letter. That will remove the pesky space

Comment: Thank you so much! This does answer the problem of trailing spaces, but I forgot to mention that the first field is optional and in that case this doesn't work, because it forces to catch a character which isn't there. It was my fault forgetting to mention that (I added it now). I'll try to find a way to figure that out, but I cannot consider this as definite correct answer as of yet because it would be misleading, but I upped the answer ;-).

Comment: I just needed to add a question mark outside the group of that expression. So, this answer really helped me solve my problem. After checking this site's rules I think I can consider this as the correct answer.